# Kubuntu 22.04 splash logo displaced after the first packages update

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, 22.04, plymouth

I installed Kubuntu 22.04 in my old laptop to give a try. All when fine but I noticed that the splash logo shows displaced to the bottom after the first package update. I remember that it was fine in the first boot after the system was installed.

[splash example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WWQF.jpg)

Any idea or suggestion? Do you know if this issue has been reported to Kubuntu team.

I'm using Nvidia drivers and x11.

Regards
Galder

Answer (score 0):

Answered directly by Ubuntu team

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-settings/+bug/1979912